# Swift: Apply LUT (Lookup Table) to an image using CIColorCube slow performance

Tags: swift, thumbnails, core-image, cifilter

I'm applying a LUT (from a .png - [Example LUT Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrhTA.png)) to an image using CIColorCube. It works well. The only problem I'm facing is that **when I create the buttons thumbnails the app stops for a few seconds.**

**The buttons look like this ->** [Buttons Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Fep.jpg)

This is my code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var filtersScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var filters = ["-", "Filter1", "Filter2", "Filter3", "Filter4"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        createFilters()
    }
    
    func createFilters() {
        var x: CGFloat = 10
        let y: CGFloat = 0
        let width: CGFloat = 60
        let height: CGFloat = 83
        let gap: CGFloat = 2
    
        for i in 0..<filters.count {
            let filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
            filterButton.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
            filterButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            filterButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0), for: .normal)
            
            let text = UILabel()
            text.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height - 21, width: filterButton.frame.width, height: 21)
            text.textAlignment = .center
            text.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
            text.textColor = .white
            text.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 8.5, weight: .medium)
            
            filterButton.addSubview(text)
            filtersScrollView.insertSubview(filterButton, at: 1)
            
            x += width + gap
    
            if i == 0 {
                filterButton.setImage(originalImage, for: .normal)
                text.text = "-"
                text.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1215686275, green: 0.1215686275, blue: 0.1215686275, alpha: 1)
            }
            else {
                // THIS LINE MAKES THE APP STOP FOR A FEW SECONDS
                let filteredImage = filterFromLUT(inputImage: originalCIImage, lut: "\(filters[i])")?.outputImage
                filterButton.setImage(UIImage(ciImage: filteredImage!), for: .normal)
                text.text = "\(filters[i])"
            }
        }
        
        filtersScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: x, height: height)
    }
    
    func filterFromLUT(inputImage: CIImage, lut: String) -> CIFilter? {
        let dimension = 64
        
        let lutImage = UIImage(named: lut)!.cgImage
        let width = lutImage!.width
        let height = lutImage!.height
        let rowNum = width / dimension
        let columnNum = height / dimension
        
        let bitmap = createBitmap(image: lutImage!)
    
        let dataSize = dimension * dimension * dimension * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4
        var array = Array<Float>(repeating: 0, count: dataSize)
    
        var bitmapOffest: Int = 0
        var z: Int = 0
    
        for _ in stride(from: 0, to: rowNum, by: 1) {
          for y in stride(from: 0, to: dimension, by: 1) {
            let tmp = z
            for _ in stride(from: 0, to: columnNum, by: 1) {
              for x in stride(from: 0, to: dimension, by: 1) {
    
                let dataOffset = (z * dimension * dimension + y * dimension + x) * 4
    
                let position = bitmap!
                  .advanced(by: bitmapOffest)
    
                array[dataOffset + 0] = Float(position
                  .advanced(by: 0)
                  .pointee) / 255
    
                array[dataOffset + 1] = Float(position
                  .advanced(by: 1)
                  .pointee) / 255
    
                array[dataOffset + 2] = Float(position
                  .advanced(by: 2)
                  .pointee) / 255
    
                array[dataOffset + 3] = Float(position
                  .advanced(by: 3)
                  .pointee) / 255
    
                bitmapOffest += 4
              }
              z += 1
            }
            z = tmp
          }
          z += columnNum
        }
    
        free(bitmap)
    
        let data = Data.init(bytes: array, count: dataSize)
        
        // Create CIColorCube filter
        let filter = CIFilter.colorCube()
        filter.inputImage = inputImage
        filter.cubeData = data
        filter.cubeDimension = Float(dimension)
    
        return filter
    }
    
    func createBitmap(image: CGImage) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>? {
        let width = image.width
        let height = image.height
    
        let bitsPerComponent = 8
        let bytesPerRow = width * 4
        
        let bitmapSize = bytesPerRow * height
    
        guard let data = malloc(bitmapSize) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let context = CGContext(
            data: data,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
            bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue,
            releaseCallback: nil,
            releaseInfo: nil)
    
        context!.draw(image, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    
        return data.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: bitmapSize)
    }
```

I think that maybe the CGContext inside the createBitmap() function is causing this. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to improve performance:

- Currently, you are processing the original input image (which I assume is pretty large) just to display the result in a 60 x 83 button. Consider scaling the image down *first* before putting it through the filters.
- You can avoid blocking the UI by making the image processing code asynchronous. Just create the buttons in their proper size and `DispatchQueue.global().async { ... }` the image processing.
- Don't use `.setImage(UIImage(ciImage: filteredImage)`. In my experience creating a `UIImage` from a `CIImage` this way to very unpredictable. Rather use a `CIContext` to render the filtered image into a `CGImage` and convert that into a `UIImage` afterward. Also try to re-use a single `CIContext` instead of re-creating it again for each image.
- The code for converting the LUT image into a float data array can be sped-up by using vDSP (see below).

Using vDSP for creating the LUT data:

```
let lutImage = UIImage(named: lut)!.cgImage
let dimension = lutImage.height

// get data from image
let lutImageData = lutImage.dataProvider?.data
let lutImageDataPtr = CFDataGetBytePtr(lutImageData)!

// convert to float and divide by 255
let numElements = dimension * dimension * dimension * 4
let inDataFloat = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: numElements)
vDSP_vfltu8(lutImageDataPtr, 1, inDataFloat, 1, vDSP_Length(numElements))
var div: Float = 255.0
vDSP_vsdiv(inDataFloat, 1, &div, inDataFloat, 1, vDSP_Length(numElements))

// convert buffer pointer to data
let lutData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: inDataFloat, length: numElements * MemoryLayout<Float>.size, freeWhenDone: true)
```

Comment: Hey Frank! I'm using the code you wrote above for creating the LUT data, but this line:
`vDSP_vfltu8(lutImageDataPtr, 1, inDataFloat, 1, vDSP_Length(numElements))`
is causing this error: **malloc: can't allocate region**.

I tried using `let dimension = 64` and the error disappeared, but the image result is definitely not the expected. What should I do?

Comment: Ah, sorry. In my LUTs all slices are in one row (instead of your 8x8 grid). I feel this is advantageous because the color cube filter expects the data in the same layout.

Comment: Ok, I tried with a neutral one-row LUT and the performance is clearly faster. But the returning image is kinda purple...

Comment: You may also need to specify the color space of the LUT. Use `CIFilter.colorCubeWithColorSpace` as filter and set `filter.colorSpace = lutImage.colorSpace`.

Comment: This is the result now with a neutral LUT https://imgur.com/a/rD4909p , the first image is the original, the other ones should be equal

Comment: This is the neutral LUT I'm using https://imgur.com/a/dcrdDdq

Comment: That's odd... Are you by chance still using a `CGContext` to get the image data?

Comment: If so, please try using this `bitmapInfo` setting: `CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue)`. This is the setting for the native `BGRA` format.

Comment: I replaced my old code with the one in your answer. This `bitmapInfo` setting update should be added to my previous code?

Comment: Ok, nevermind then. Your results look like some color channels got mixed up, but I honestly don't know how this could be happening at the moment...

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Given a .cube file, how to extract data out of it for use in CIColorCube?

Comment: @DeepakSharma I'm pretty sure there is no built-in support for those files. I'm afraid you need to write your own parser for them.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel I found a way using png images instead of .cube files. AdobeLUTParser is there to parse .lut files but the method is slow. Still struggling with some performance issues, have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404956/cifilter-color-cube-data-loading